# Chrome não aplica o Addclass antes de chamar o window.confirm

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, confirm

**Problema:**

O Chrome não está renderizando a minha classe `addclass` antes da chamada da minha janela de confirmação `window.confirm` é como se ficasse travado e fosse liberado só depois do confirm.

O que fiz foi colocar a chamada da função `ConfirmaExclusao` em `OnClientClick` de um `image button` que está dentro de um `TemplateField` num `gridview`, a intenção do confirm quando retorna `false` é não chamar o `RowCommand` no qual efetiva exclusão.

Esta solução para o IE 9, 10 e 11 funciona, mas pro chrome não...

**Exemplo:**

Tem um exemplo aqui do problema http://jsfiddle.net/BvMFs/2/ podem ver que para o chrome a classe é aplicada depois da saida da janela de confirm.

**Minhas Funções javascript:**

```
function MarcarLinha(linha) {
    //Soma 2 na linha (1 linha do Cabeçalho e mais uma poque o TR da grid começa em 1, não em zero)
    linha = linha + 2;

    //Limpa todas as marcações
    $('[id$=gridViewListaCondicoesComlRCTRVI]').find('tr').each(function (row) {
        $(this).removeClass('hover_row');
    });

    $('[id$=gridViewListaCondicoesComlRCTRVI] tr:nth-child(' + linha + ')').addClass('hover_row');
}

function ConfirmaExclusao(linha) {
    MarcarLinha(linha);

    //Confirmar a exlusão
    if (window.confirm('Deseja realmente excluir este registro?'))
        return true;
    else {
        //$('[id$=gridViewListaCondicoesComlRCTRVI] tr:nth-child(' + linha + ')').removeClass("hover_row");
            return false;
    }
}
```

**Meu ImageButton dentro do gridview:**

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnExcluir32" runat="server" CommandName="Excluir" CommandArgument='<%#Container.DataItemIndex%>'
    ImageUrl="~/images/delete.png" OnClientClick='<%# "return ConfirmaExclusao(" + ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex + ");" %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O javascript é uma função interpretada, e o browser interpreta ela linha por linha. Porém o browser faz isso de maneira muito rápida onde acaba executando as linhas abaixo da chamada da função antes mesmo da função ser executada.

Para evitar este tipo de problema, vc pode utilizar a técnica de callback:

```
function MarcarLinha(linha, callback) {
    //Soma 2 na linha (1 linha do Cabeçalho e mais uma poque o TR da grid começa em 1, não em zero)
    linha = linha + 2;

    //Limpa todas as marcações
    $('[id$=gridViewListaCondicoesComlRCTRVI]').find('tr').each(function (row) {
       $(this).removeClass('hover_row');
    });

    $('[id$=gridViewListaCondicoesComlRCTRVI] tr:nth-child(' + linha + ')').addClass('hover_row');

    callback(); // A função passada será executada aqui
}

function ConfirmaExclusao(linha) {
    MarcarLinha(linha, function() {
        //Confirmar a exlusão
        if (window.confirm('Deseja realmente excluir este registro?'))
            return true;
        else {
            //$('[id$=gridViewListaCondicoesComlRCTRVI] tr:nth-child(' + linha + ')').removeClass("hover_row");
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Espero ter ajudado!